# How to embed ics file into google calendar

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm new to using the Google Calendar API.

I can create .ics calendars using a php app.
I would like to know if it is possible for Google Calendar to allow embedding of those calendars on to my website without having to add it to an account. I really like the google interface, and if this could work in any way, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to say "no". To utilize the Google Calendar interface (e.g. widget) on your website and have it display calendar data that you've created (.ics via your PHP app), at some point, that data needs to be loaded into a Google Calendar account.